# How can I get the longest increasing subsequence in a string?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm pretty rusty on my Java skills but I was trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter a string and displays a maximum length increasing ordered subsequence of characters. For example, if the user entered `Welcome` the program would output `Welo`. If the user entered `WWWWelllcommmeee`, the program would still output `Welo`. I've gotten this much done but it's not doing what it should be and I'm honestly at a loss as to why.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stuff {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a string. ");
    String userString = input.next();
    ArrayList charList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList finalList = new ArrayList();
    int currentLength = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < userString.length(); i++){
        charList.add(userString.charAt(i));

        for(int j = i; j < userString.length(); j++){
            int k=j+1;
            if(k < userString.length() && userString.charAt(k) > userString.charAt(j)){
                charList.add(userString.charAt(j));
                currentLength++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(max < currentLength){
        max = currentLength;
        finalList.addAll(charList);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < finalList.size(); i++){
        char item = (char) finalList.get(i);
        System.out.print(item);
    }

    int size1 = charList.size();
    int size2 = finalList.size();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Size 1 is: " + size1 + " Size 2 is : " + size2);    
  }
 }
```

My code, if I input `Welcome`, outputs `WWeceeclcccome`.

Does anyone have some tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should learn how to debug to find your own errors. Use the debug features integrated in the IDE, or use the old but powerful "system.out.print" to log and see where your code goes wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In these cases it tends to help to step away from the keyboard and think about the algorithm you're trying to implement. Try to explain it first in words.

You are constructing a list of individual characters by appending each of the characters in the input string followed by characters to its right that are in correct alphabetical with their successor. For the input "Welcome" this means the accumulated output will be, showing the outer loop in vertical and inner loop in horizontal:

```
W W e c
e e c
l c
c c
o
m
e
```

In total: WWeceeclccome

Comment: Plus 1 for stating it helps to step away from the keyboard. A problem like this, you should know what the algorithm is you want to implement, before you implement it. The algorithm wouldn't have to be correct on the first try, but at least you have a reference point. Look where your algorithm is flawed, or see where your implementation differs from your design.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the logic of this implementation. Here is a faster solution which runs in O(nlogn) time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stuff
{   
    //return the index of the first element that's not less than the target element
    public static int bsearch(char[] arr, int size, int key)
    {
        int left = 0;
        int right = size - 1;
        int mid;
        while (left <= right)
        {
            mid = (left + right) / 2;
            if(arr[mid] < key)
                left = mid + 1;
            else
                right = mid - 1;
        }
        return left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        String userString = input.next();


        char[] maxArr = new char[userString.length()];
        char[] precedent = new char[userString.length()];
        maxArr[0] = userString.charAt(0);
        precedent[0] = userString.charAt(0);
        int len = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < userString.length(); i++)
        {
            if(userString.charAt(i) > maxArr[len - 1])
            {
                maxArr[len] = userString.charAt(i);
                precedent[len] = userString.charAt(i);
                len++;
            }
            else
                maxArr[bsearch(maxArr, len, userString.charAt(i))] = userString.charAt(i);
        }

        //System.out.println(len);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            System.out.print(precedent[i]);

    }

 }
```

Comment: this program when ran on `"banana"` returns bn which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dynamic Programming O(N^2) in lexicography order mean if i/p is abcbcbcd then o/p can be abcccd, abbbcd, abbccd but as per lexicography order o/p will be abbbcd.

```
public static String longestIncreasingSubsequence(String input1) {
    int dp[] = new int[input1.length()];
    int i,j,max = 0;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    /* Initialize LIS values for all indexes */
     for ( i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++ )
        dp[i] = 1;

     /* Compute optimized LIS values in bottom up manner */
     for ( i = 1; i < input1.length(); i++ )
        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) 
              if (input1.charAt(i) >= input1.charAt(j) && dp[i] < dp[j]+1)
                  dp[i] = dp[j] + 1;

     /* Pick maximum of all LIS values */
     for ( i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++ ) {
        if ( max < dp[i] ) {
             max = dp[i];
             if (i + 1 < input1.length() && max == dp[i+1] && input1.charAt(i+1) < input1.charAt(i)) {
                 str.append(input1.charAt(i+1));
                 i++;
             } else {
                 str.append(input1.charAt(i)); 
             }
        }
     }
     return str.toString();
}
```